# Regex string after one or two words

Tags: java, python, php, regex, regex-group

I try to get last string after one or two defined words. This is my actual Regex:

```
 /(?i)(?:(ticket|number))\.?\s?\:?\s*?([^\s]+)
```

And I want to get the ticket number from this list of possibilities:

```
ticket number A2-177653     
ticket : A2-177653     
number 454544
```

Therefore the regex can have "ticket" or "number" or "ticket number"

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?i)(?:ticket(?:\s+number)?|number)\.?\s?:?\s*(\S+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EdGsJE/4)

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive modifier
- `(?:ticket(?:\s+number)?|number)` - `ticket`, `number` or `ticket number`
- `\.?` - an optional `.`
- `\s?:?\s*` - an optional whitespace, an optional `:` and then 0+ whitespaces
- `(\S+)` - Group 1: any one or more non-whitespace chars.